# External Monitor will not turn off from inactivity

Tags: usb, suspend, external-monitor

I have a USB keyboard, USB mouse, and USB hub connected to my laptop. I am using two external monitors. My laptop is closed so I am not using my laptop monitor.

I have the monitors turn off after X minutes of inactivity. The problem is it won't work.

I have used the terminal to manually turn off the monitor. Monitor turns off and then it turns back on right away.

I suspect that a USB device is causing my computer to come out of inactivity which turns the monitor back on.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out after seeing someone's comment on another post.

I am using 2 Dell Ultrasharp U2719D. The Auto Select feature of the monitor re-wakes the monitor. After turning off the Auto Select feature, my monitor is able to stay off from inactivity.